# Ecommerce Single Product Next Product Link

Tags: navigation, plugin-wp-e-commerce

I have tried using the default wp next and previous link but when click it would go to another category post instead of the next post(product)

```
previous_post('&laquo; &laquo; %', 'previous', 'yes'); 
next_post('% &raquo; &raquo; ', 'next', 'yes');
```

when i try to put yes for the same category, the previous and next title disappears

```
previous_post('&laquo; &laquo; %', 'previous', 'yes','yes'); 
next_post('% &raquo; &raquo; ', 'next', 'yes','yes');
```

I also tried using

```
wpsc_first_products_link
wpsc_last_products_link
```

Answer (score 1):

[next_post](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/next_post) function is deprecated.

You should try this instead: [next_post_link](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/next_post_link) and [previous_post_link](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/previous_post_link)

The basic way to use it is like so:
This will link to the next post or prev post.

```
<?php 
    next_post_link( '%link', '%title' );
    previous_post_link( '%link', '%title' ); 
?>
```

If you would like to link to the next post in the same category, add true after '%title'. This will work for the default posts and category.

```
<?php 
    next_post_link( '%link', '%title', true ); 
    previous_post_link( '%link', '%title', true ); 
?>
```

If you are using a CUSTOM POST TYPE with a CUSTOM TAXONOMY (like a product post), then you have to tell the function which taxonomy to look for the next post. eg.

```
<?php 
    next_post_link( '%link', '%title', true, '', 'custom_taxonomy' ); 
    previous_post_link( '%link', '%title', true, '', 'custom_taxonomy' ); 
?>
```

All the above examples have been tested and working.

Comment: i did try that but setting it to true doesnt make the next link visible at all

Comment: if you add both next_post_link and previous_post_link. Do they both not show up? And also are there other posts in that category.

Comment: yes that is correct. and yes i have 10 post in one category.

Comment: What is the category?

Comment: a product category in wp ecommerce

Comment: to be precise i am adding a next and previous in the single product page

Comment: See my updated answer

Comment: I already tried that, when you set it to 'true' link text will  disappears